# Hide other copies of component in angular?

Tags: angular, popup, components, angular5

I have a pop up component which is visible whenever a user clicks to show the pop up button . I am using that component at multiple places on a single page to display information . Now if i click on a pop , I want the rest of the copies of the component to hide .

for eg: If i clicked on a pop up for user info , then i click on the other pop up , i want the user info pop up to hide

I have solved this issue by assigning an id to every copy of the component , and hiding the rest except the one that is being clicked

Is there any other way to hide the rest of the copies of the component other than the one that is clicked ?

Comment: firstly ,If you have a single component for pop up it is best not to copy it multiple times and just change what you want with Inputs , this way you don't need to hide and you can just modify your pop up.
But if somehow you need to copy over and over again try to assign `*ngIf` to your popup components html tags, something like `*ngif="state == 'firstCondition'"` and only change the state wherever you need to

Comment: when i said multiple copies , i meant something like this 
<div *ngFor= "x of y"> <pop-up-component> </pop-up-component> </div>

here we have multiple copies of component being generated as each this points to individual component

Answer (score 0):

Add global listener and if click was outside this component - close it.
For example check [Handling multiple components with click events in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108773/handling-multiple-components-with-click-events-in-angular/52110539?noredirect=1#comment91176903_52110539)